# How to load kedro DataSet object dynamically

Tags: python, kedro

I am currently using the yaml api to create all of my datasets with `kedro==15.5`.  I would like to be able to peer into this information from time to time dynamically.  It appears that I can get to this information with the `io.datasets` which is a `_FrozenDatasets` object.  I cannot loop over it or access it programatically though.

**Specific Use Case**

Specifically I would like to add a test that loops over the datasets to check that there are not multiple catalog entries using the same filepath.  Is this possible without using eval?  Currently I think would need to do something like this

```py
filepaths = {}
for entry_name in io.list()
   eval(f'filepaths[{entry_name}] = io.datasets.{entry_name}'.filepath)
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I don't think `AbstractDataSet` (from which they are all defined) has a property for filepath or the config that built it.  You can read the `ProjectContext` config but that won't cover datasets that were dynamically built.